# What to do with users making lots of pointless edits?

Tags: discussion, edits

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered) which has been locked for almost 2 years get bumped back into the main feed, and when I checked out the revision that bumped it, I see that [this user has lots of little edits of 1 character which are just whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97010/muhammad-akhtar?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_revisions) which are doing nothing but bumping things needlessly.  Maybe he's grinding for Copy Editor, maybe he's just bumping stuff he likes, but it seems a bit excessive.

What's the community view on folks who make massive amounts of "non-edits" like these and what's the preferred way of dealing with it?

Comment: Typos, misspellings and grammatical errors drive me nuts (not that I'm immune to them), so I like to correct them when reading a question. I only do it for "recent" questions, but I do get tempted at times when searching for answers through long-since-closed questions.

Comment: @PengOne - These aren't typo fixes. Just blank edits.

Comment: @PengOne: important thing may be whether it's single character change (for example whitespace, or comma instead of half-comma) or something more important (multiple typos in title and something else).

Comment: I didn't think that was allowed? Isn't there a minimum number of character changes? Perhaps deleting white space should not count towards that limit.

Comment: @PengOne in some cases adjusting only whitespace is very necessary, for example, editing Python code snippets.  Or for that matter, simply (re-)indenting code.

Comment: @PengOne That limit only applies to users with less than 2000 reputation.

Comment: Left comment for editor (and flagged moderator) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered/184638#184638).

Comment: Wait, what? You can edit answers on locked questions? That feels like a bug.

Comment: Ah, I guess this might have been about revoking old upvotes. (Google cache shows this user upvoted 587 times on March 9th, but the profile only shows 577 upvotes right now. Even then a revision comment might have been nice.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This feels like abuse.  If I were mod I'd shoot him an email asking him to stop (or perhaps just leave a comment asking him to stop).  If the behavior continued I'd give him a short suspension. (If it continued beyond that, I'd suspend for a longer period of time.)

Comment: At least a week in the bin for such abuse

Comment: @random start with a warning

Comment: random and warning in the same sentence? What's going on here?

Comment: looks like he's been dealt with already, but that's a good suggestion